# error: `value` does not live long enough label: borrow later used here

Tags: rust

I have a function and I don't know how to fix the error:

The error finds place here:  obj.insert(key, &value);

I get:

```
error: `value` does not live long enough
label: borrow later used here
error: `value` does not live long enough
label: borrowed value does not live long enough
`value` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enoughrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
utils.rs(18, 5): `value` dropped here while still borrowed
utils.rs(17, 9): borrow later used here
```

```rust
pub fn register_client(
    host: &str,
    uid: &str,
    machine_details: HashMap<&str, String>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let uri = format!("{}/register", host);
    let mut obj = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    obj.insert("uid", uid);

    // Add machine details to the object
    for (key, value) in machine_details {
        obj.insert(key, &value);
    }

    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let res = client.post(uri).json(&obj).send();

    if res.is_ok() {
        println!("{}", res.unwrap().text().unwrap());
    } else {
        if res.unwrap_err().is_connect() {
            println!("No connection to C2 server.");
        } else {
            println!("Unknown error.");
        }
    }
    return Ok(());
}
```

Comment: Hot tip, the full compiler diagnostic, which you get by clicking, usually includes valuable information, for you and for the random SO person that you want help from. Also you should use (````'```lang-none' and '```'````) before and after the error message to keep the formatting.

Comment: You're consuming `machine_details` in the for loop. Iterate over `&machine_details` instead (or use `extend`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (key /* : &str */, value /* : String */) in machine_details {
//                     ^^^^^----+
    obj.insert(key, &value); // | gets dropped here
// v----------------------------+
}
```

The for loop takes ownership of `machine_details` and its items, causing them to get dropped by the end of the loop, invalidating the references to `value`.

You can instead iterate over references to `machine_details`'s items:

```
for (key /* : &&str */, value /* : &String */) in &machine_details {
    obj.insert(key, value);
}
```